# "Return Key" for terminal on a spanish (windows) keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

Does anyone know which key is "return key" in spanish keyboard (windows) or is there a way to bind the key without shutting down?

Comment: It appears the Return/Enter key is where it is on most keyboards: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/74/KB_Spanish.svg/400px-KB_Spanish.svg.png

Comment: Tried enter key and didn't work, checked the layout too you are correct its the enter key but exits the terminal

Comment: And this is in general, or are you in some setup?

Comment: Trying to install steam and the terminal (part of installation) require to input with "return key" at the end, but enter closes the terminal window.

Comment: end of what? What's the prompt?

Comment: once I click install on the deb file from steam site, terminal starts installation I click "Y" on everything until says input "Return key" then it simply closes if I click it, I tried other keys and nothing.

Comment: Why not just install the DEB through the Software Center?

Comment: Hey zach, I tried but won't work no message nothing

Answer (score 0):

The return key is either key labeled "Intro" as shown below:

[image: Spanish keyboard]